# Basic function could not be found, if I include jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is such a basic thing, I could not figure out.  Consider the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

        function Show(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onClick="Show('hello');" value="Show 1" />
</body>
</html>
```

The above sample works fine if I exclude "jquery" include.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try closing your import script tag instead of just a `/>`

Comment: Wow...that worked...could not imagine it would be that worse, if I use just "/>".  Thanks sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is because self closing script tags do not work. use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

**[Link to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)**

Comment: Good to know this.  So strange that I did not even receive any error for that, in any browser.